# 'There is a column named "question_id" in table "subjects", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.'

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I am using node-postgressql to create and put data into my Elephant SQL. I was able to create the table and seed one of the tables using JSON file but in the second table it is giving me an error

I have created to tables and linked them as above

```js
await pool.query("CREATE TABLE questions (id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, question text NOT NULL, answer text NOT NULL)")

await pool.query("CREATE TABLE subjects ( id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, question_id INT REFERENCES questions(id), subject TEXT NOT NULL)")
```

Then I am using a json file to populate the data in these tables as below

```
 return await pool.query("INSERT INTO questions (question, answer) (SELECT question, answer FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::questions, $1::JSON));", [JSON.stringify(questions)])
```

```
return await pool.query("INSERT INTO subjects (question_id, subject) (SELECT  question_id, subject FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::questions, $1::JSON));", [JSON.stringify(subject)])
```

I am able to insert the data in questions table but when I do the same for the subjects table it gives me the below error

> There is a column named "question_id" in table "subjects", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.'

can someone please let me know why am I getting this error what am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1) You need to add to your question examples of the JSON you are expanding with `json_populate_recordset`. 2) I'm betting there is no `question_id` key in  the  `subject` objects.

Comment: In the INSERT for the subjects table you are using `NULL::questions,...` - that should be: `NULL::subjects, ...`. Also: the parentheses around the SELECT are useless noise.